# Recursive CTE in Spark SQL for year and month

Tags: apache-spark

The CTE below is successful in T-SQL. However I wish to implement the same CTE in **Spark SQL**.
When trying this it says :

> Table or view not found:  YearMonthCTE; line 12 pos 23;

```
 WITH YearMonthCTE (jaar,maand) AS
(
           SELECT      1988    AS jaar,
                       1       AS maand
           UNION ALL
           SELECT      CASE WHEN maand < 12 THEN jaar
                            ELSE jaar + 1
                       END as jaar,
                       CASE WHEN maand < 12 THEN maand + 1
                            ELSE 1
                       END as maand
           FROM        YearMonthCTE
           where jaar <2023
        
)

select * from YearMonthCTE where jaar < 2023
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Most of the time T-SQL and Spark SQL are alike, but now I can't figure out the difference

Comment: Please use proper code formatting when writing questions.